# Hiera and dependencies between classes

Tags: windows, deployment, puppet, hiera

Is is possible to define dependencies between two classes in Hiera? Lets say that you have a class A that installs a service and class B that will configure this service. In this example how do you create a dependency between those classes? Will something like this work?

```
---
classes:
  - 'B':
    require: Class[A]
```

Comment: Why would you want to rely on Hiera to express an inherent property of your classes?  Or if it's not an inherent property, then why would you want to place an unnecessary order-of application constraint?

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. I have two classes that are dependents on each other. This has nothing to do with inherent properties. This is not my real issue, it is just an example. The real issue is more complicated to explain and thats why I choose to simplify the example. I would like to do this in hiera to keep the code more organized.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a function available that will mold any data definition into class or even resource relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this inside the Puppet DSL. It's easiest to make a module that wraps the other modules, then include that inside Hiera.

The wrapper module can then use the Puppet ordering tools, such as `require`, which:

> The require function declares a class and causes it to become a dependency of the surrounding container.

Some examples of this are in the Puppet documentation [Relationships and Ordering](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#syntax-the-require-function).

Here are two examples of this wrapper module being used that are on that documentation page:

Using Require:

```
class wordpress {
  require apache
  require mysql
  ...
}
```

Using arrow chaining:

```
class apache::ssl {
  include site::certificates
  # Restart every service in this class if any of our SSL certificates change on disk:
  Class['site::certificates'] ~> Class['apache::ssl']
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing exactly that as you suggested. Thank you.